# JFace different instances of dropped POJO

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, swt, jface

I have a `Label` wrapped in a *POJO*. All external operations are delegated to the label.

I (internally) hook a `DragSource` to the said `Label`. Transfer is `LocalSelectionTransfer`.

Implementation of `DragSourceAdapter`:

```
@Override public void dragSetData(DragSourceEvent e)
{
      transfer.setSelection(new StructuredSelection(this)); // *this* is the POJO wrapper
}
```

**Question**:

On drop events (externally), if I do

```
final Object newObj = ((StructuredSelection) transfer.getSelection()).getFirstElement();
```

newObj would be `POJO$1`, or `POJO$2` etc.

What's the reason? Why don't I get an **instanceof** `POJO`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, `new StructuredSelection(this)` is inside the implementation of `DragSourceAdapter`, so `this` is the implementation (an anonymous inner class of your "POJO") instead of the POJO itself! You need instead `new StructuredSelection(POJO.this)` to refer to the outer instance (obviously, replace `POJO` with the actual name of your class).

A bit of an aside, but I wouldn't call a class which is concerned with GUI directly a "POJO".